# uniform_real_distribution not giving uniform distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I am trying to generate high quality random numbers in the range (0,1) in my project and I tried testing the `uniform_real_distribution`from a sample code from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/). When I ran it the code it worked fine but when I tried to modify the same with seeding the generator like:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
// obtain a seed from the system clock:
unsigned seed = static_cast<int> (chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

// globally defining the generator and making it static for safety because in the
// actual project this might affect the flow.

static default_random_engine gen(seed);
uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);

int main(){
  const int nrolls=10000;  // number of experiments
  const int nstars=95;     // maximum number of stars to distribute
  const int nintervals=10; // number of intervals

  int p[nintervals]={};

  for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) {
    double number = distribution(gen);
    ++p[int(nintervals*number)];
  }

  std::cout << "uniform_real_distribution (0.0,1.0):" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::fixed; std::cout.precision(1);

  for (int i=0; i<nintervals; ++i) {
    std::cout << float(i)/nintervals << "-" << float(i+1)/nintervals << ": ";
    std::cout << std::string(p[i]*nstars/nrolls,'*') << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;

}
```

The random numbers were not uniformly distributed. The output of the same when executed repeatedly is:

> F:\path>randtest
>
> uniform_real_distribution (0.0,1.0):
>
> 0.0-0.1: *********
>
> 0.1-0.2: **********
>
> 0.2-0.3: ********
>
> 0.3-0.4: *********
>
> 0.4-0.5: *********
>
> 0.5-0.6: *********
>
> 0.6-0.7: *********
>
> 0.7-0.8: *********
>
> 0.8-0.9: *********
>
> 0.9-1.0: **********
>
> F:\path>randtest
>
> uniform_real_distribution (0.0,1.0):
>
> 0.0-0.1: *********
>
> 0.1-0.2: *********
>
> 0.2-0.3: *********
>
> 0.3-0.4: *********
>
> 0.4-0.5: *********
>
> 0.5-0.6: *********
>
> 0.6-0.7: *********
>
> 0.7-0.8: *********
>
> 0.8-0.9: *********
>
> 0.9-1.0: *********
>
> F:\path>randtest
>
> uniform_real_distribution (0.0,1.0):
>
> 0.0-0.1: *********
>
> 0.1-0.2: *********
>
> 0.2-0.3: *********
>
> 0.3-0.4: *********
>
> 0.4-0.5: **********
>
> 0.5-0.6: *********
>
> 0.6-0.7: *********
>
> 0.7-0.8: *********
>
> 0.8-0.9: *********
>
> 0.9-1.0: *********

Is it because of the seeding? or is it better to use a different generator?

I use G++ 5.1.0 compiler c++11 standards.

Comment: That looks pretty uniform to me. Are you expecting the results to be perfectly evenly distributed every time?

Comment: Yes. This function will be called a multiple time and each result are compared with each other so is there a way to get it perfectly distributed?

Comment: Consult a statistician if it's terribly important to you, but I'm guessing your sample is too small. When I increase `nrolls` by 10X I get a visually uniform distribution.

Comment: @akki: Sure. Generate a sequence of increasing values starting at 0, with each successive value at an increment of `1.0/nRolls` (or `1.0/(nRolls - 1)` if you want it to be right inclusive). Then shuffle.

Comment: Random numbers don't generate perfect histograms.  They are, well, random.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you flipped a coin once and it landed heads, would it always land on tails the next time you flipped it?

A coin produces a uniform distribution on the set `{heads, tails}`.  That doesn't mean for any set of flips, the number of heads and tails is equal.  In fact, the chance of that happening *exactly* goes *down* as you flip more coins.

In your case, each of those intervals have a 10% chance of being selected.

The variance of such a selection is (0.1)(1-.1), or 0.09.

The expected value is 0.1.

After 10000 attempts, the expected value is going to be 1000.

Tha variance is going to be 900.

900 variance corresponds to a standard deviation of 30.

The 95-ish% confidence interval is 2 standard deviations (actually 1.96, but who cares).

So you should expect the values to typically be between 940 and 1060.

With 95 stars, each star corresponds to 10000/95=105 elements.

940/105 is approx 8.95
1060/105 is approx 10.06

So you'll usually see between 8 and 10 stars on each column.  Assuming rounding down, hitting 7 or 11 stars should be very rare (as that is 3 SD away) even on 10 anti-correlated samples.

This all assumes a perfect uniform random distribution.  As this models your observed behavior, your problem is with mathematics and the definition of uniform *random* distribution, not the C++ language.

If you want a perfect histogram, don't use a uniform random distribution.  For example, you could simply start with 0, then add 0.0001 each time.  After 10001 calls you'll have a uniform histogram from 0 to 1.

Uniform random simply means the chance of each region is the same.

Comment: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html says normal=1000, sd=30, range=945-1050 -> 91.88% ought to have 9 stars. 3.334% with 8 stars, and 4.78% with 10 stars.  This seems to match his examples quite nicely

Comment: @Yakk thank you for the explaination. and it is true that i am new to this topic of mathematics, your reply helped me understand better.